# Similar to rows-to-col(EAV to relational) - SQL query please, contd

Tags: sql, plsql

This question is related to:

[Similar to rows-to-col(EAV to relational) - SQL query please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516710/similar-to-rows-to-coleav-to-relational-sql-query-please)

As suggested in that forum we are in the process of restructuring the schema. But as we have to support 
existing app, I would like to ask another related question:

Data is in the following format:

[image: Original data]

And I need in following format:

[image: data format required]

PROD_QTY is not involved now. PROD_KEY need to be placed in their respective column based on EN_NO as shown above. Tried out GROUP BY with CASE but to no avail. Suggestions??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If your using oracle 11g then pivot may be of some use:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Thanks @A.B.Cade but I am using 10g and I don't think decode function works here. Here we need to group the individual keys to their category column based on EN_NO. May be some soft of cursor is evolved here but I am not getting it to work.